# How do I replace a class variable for the duration of a single test in Python?

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-3.x, python-unittest

I'm trying to test a cache class where old items should be automatically deleted. The amount of items the cache can hold is controlled by a "constant" class variable like this:

```
class Cache(dict):
    MAX_ITEMS = 100
```

For testing purposes I would like to change that constant for the duration of a single test case. Using `unittest.mock.patch` I could replace the class variable with a `MagicMock` but that's not really what I'm trying to do. I just need to replace it with a different number.

Is there an elegant way to do this in Python (like `patch`), or should I just reset the variable myself on `tearDown`?

---

<sub>I'm using Python 3.4.3</sub>

Comment: Well you could use the `with` syntax to create a limited scope for the value inside the test, that looks not too bad. But if you need it for every testcase doing it inside the corresponding setup/teardown methods seems nicer.

Comment: @Voo What would be nice is a function like `patch` that simply makes sure the original value is restored after the test, without replacing it with a mock object

Comment: I think using `setUp` and `tearDown` is the way to go; if you don't know a different way, chances are the next reader won't either!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[Reading the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.patch) more carefully, it turns out `patch` actually has an optional argument that controls what the variable is replaced by (instead of a mock object), so I can do this:

```
class CacheTest(TestCase):
    @patch("myproject.Cache.MAX_ITEMS", new=3)
    def testCacheTrim(self):
        # ...
```

Or, as Dunes pointed out:

```
class CacheTest(TestCase):
    @patch.object(Cache, "MAX_ITEMS", new=3)
    def testCacheTrim(self):
        # ...
```

Which arguably looks prettier.

Answer (score 16):

patch can do this already. try:

```
from unittest.mock import patch

class A:
    val = 1

assert A.val == 1
with patch.object(A, "val", "patched_value"):
    assert A.val == "patched_value"

assert A.val == 1
```

Of course you can use `patch.object` as a decorator as well.

Answer (score 0):

You could consider providing a class constructor that sets MAX_ITEMS. Something like:

```
class Cache(dict):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.MAX_ITEMS = kwargs.get("MAX_ITEMS", 100)  # default value

    @classmethod
    def create_with_max(cls, MAX_ITEMS, *args, **kwargs):
        return cls(MAX_ITEMS=MAX_ITEMS, *args, **kwargs)

>>> c = Cache.create_with_max(40)
>>> c.MAX_ITEMS
40
```

This would allow you to set the cache size (during testing or otherwise)